# Jenkins: string parameter not working properly

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have a job with a string parameter and i have a strange behavior when using that as an argument on a script.
My string parameter is called COMMIT_MSG

I'm doing the following on "Build - Execute shell":

```
COMMIT_ARG="-c \"$COMMIT_MSG\""
echo $COMMIT_ARG
echo "## Run the script"
./myscript $COMMIT_ARG
```

And i have the following output:

```
23:44:17 + COMMIT_ARG='-c "MY MESSAGE FOR COMMIT"'
23:44:17 + echo -c '"MY' MESSAGE FOR 'COMMIT"'
23:44:17 -c "MY MESSAGE FOR COMMIT"
23:44:17 + echo '## Run the script'
23:44:17 ## Run the script
23:44:17 + ./myscript -c '"MY' MESSAGE FOR 'COMMIT"'
```

The variable seems to be set correctly and echo of it is also ok. But when i use it as an argument of the script it has this extra quotes that kill it.
When i print the argument inside my script i just have this:

```
"MY
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `COMMIT_ARG="-c $COMMIT_MSG"`

Comment: Doesn't work if parameter has more than one word. Doing that makes the argument in script to have no quotes.